# Angularjs directive scope accessing in a factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm running Angular 1.4.3.

I'm trying to create a 'factory' in angular that helps me create a common menu system in my app. The 'create' function of the 'gui' factory creates a ul and the li elements are clickable with ng-click.

This ul is attached to the document body.

The ng-click should execute the 'callMe' function in my factory, but I'm not sure what scope to use....

Code:

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute']);

App.factory('gui', function() {

    var menu = function {
        "create" : function(){
            var menu_container = $('<div id="menu"></div>');
            var menu_ul = $('<ul></ul>');
            menu_ul.append('<li class="menu-item-purple" ng-click="gui.menu.callMe()"><a>About <span style="float: right;">&gt;</span></a></li>');
            menu_container.append( menu_ul );
            menu_container.prependTo(document.body);
        },
        "callMe" : function(){
            console.log("I HAVE BEEN HIT");
        }
    }
    return {
        "menu" : menu
    };
})
.controller('ExampleController', function($scope, gui){
    $scope.gui = gui;
    gui.menu.create();
})
```

So in the above code, when I click the li menu button - I do not get any response.

I have tried the following in the li element:

```
ng-click="this.callMe()"
```

I thought the original should work because if I hard code the html into the view with that ng-click directive, it works. I assume it could be something to do with load order as the gui.menu object should be present in the view as it's passed in the controller's scope?

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Since your factory actually involves with some DOM operation, I would suggest you defining a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

You can define your `ul`, `li` elements in the directive template and also handles the `ng-click` events. A directive is the best choice to share some DOM structure as well as the logic across different places in your application.

Answer (score 0):

To access the method contained within your factory in the template, you need to **change the 'this' variable to gui**, that's because your methods are contained in a variable named gui inside your scope.

Although, it may be easier to create a function inside your scope for the thing you want to do.

```
$scope.createMenu = function () { gui.menu.create(); };
```

And then, you can call the function directly in the template with

```
ng-click="createMenu()"
```

But, as @Joy said it would be better with a directive since your DOM is modified